# Recurring Location permission popups in react Js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the location of the user, who access/opened my web application.

```js
class All extends Component {
  state = {
    option: null,
    lat: null,
    long: null,
    speed: null,
    positon: null,
    message:null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      console.log("YES");
      this.setState({ option: "yes" });
    } else {
      console.log("NO");
      this.setState({ option: "no" });
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.setState({
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        long: position.coords.longitude,
        speed: position.coords.speed,
        positon: position
      });
      console.log(position);
    },error =>{
      this.setState({
        message:"Error code = "+error.code+"-"+error.message
      })
      console.log("Error code = "+error.code+"-"+error.message)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.option},
        <br />
        {this.state.lat},
        <br />
        {this.state.long},
        <br />
        {this.state.speed}
        <br />
        {this.state.message}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<All />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

at first a popup appearing requesting permission for location, but if any user deny the access , then on refreshing the page , popup menu should appear again that is the thing missing here.....

"How do I generated popup for requesting location access permission again on user refreshing my page "

component Did Update work here??

Comment: There's no way. You must tell your user to allow.

Comment: Can we create a function given to a button  , which just popup the permission popup box at onclick ... So that if permission isn't granted , user can grant .......... Function to popup permission access popup box!??

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this question